# java call a method with variable

Tags: java, mysql, string, jdbc

In need to call thıs method with variable because of using for all database tables. 
I can get all of the columns and variable type and boundary limits in one array? Which want to use within the method in a more professional way for updating all tables.I don't want to write a method for each table.Make this more generic.

```
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    java.sql.Date startDate = new java.sql.Date(calendar.getTime().getTime());
/*My array is which is come from another method:[[id, INT, 10], [MYUSER, VARCHAR, 30], [EMAIL, VARCHAR, 50], [WEBPAGE, VARCHAR, 50], [DATUM, DATE, 10], [SUMMARY, VARCHAR, 40], [COMMENTS, VARCHAR, 400]]*/
    PreparedStatement st = conn.prepareStatement("UPDATE comments SET id=?,MYUSER = ?, EMAIL = ?,WEBPAGE = ?,DATUM=?,SUMMARY=?,COMMENTS=? WHERE id = "+id+"");

    st.setInt(1, id);
    st.setString(2, element.get(0));
    st.setString(3, element.get(1));
    st.setString(4, element.get(2));
    st.setDate(5, startDate);
    st.setString(6, element.get(3));
    st.setString(7, element.get(4));

    st.executeUpdate();
    conn.close();
```

I've tried to format my code, yet I'm failing to make it a string formatted method.

Although, I wish to make the code more professional and yet more flexible; 
For example like these:

```
    String a = "set.";
    String b = "String";
    String c = "int";

    st.setInt(1, id);

    st."a+c"(2, element.get(0));
    st."a+b"(3, element.get(1));
    st."a+b"(4, element.get(2));
    st."setDate"(5, startDate);
    st."a+b"(6, element.get(3));
    st."a+b"(7, element.get(4));
```

Any ideas on how I could make it happen?

Comment: "How can i make this". Don't. This doesn't make your code more professional. Very, very much the opposite. Professional code calls the right methods for the right intents. Which is what the original code does.

Comment: Yes you can, Just create a class which hold this variables

Comment: While there is a way to do what you want with java reflection, don't do it. It will be confusing for everyone as well as yourself a few days later. Also the code will be more likely to crash and its complexity will be unnecessarily high.

Comment: If you want this flexibility, you should instead consider using existing libraries build on top of JDBC that do something like this (usually with objects, not with arrays though, arrays are not 'professional' (joking))

Comment: "call a method with variable in my code" -- well... if you want to do something like this probably you want to use an ORM. Object-Relational Mapping tools implement all those lower-level details for you.

Comment: i m using jdbc and i can get all table columns in a array like this       [[id, INT, 10], [MYUSER, VARCHAR, 30], [EMAIL, VARCHAR, 50], [WEBPAGE, VARCHAR, 50], [DATUM, DATE, 10], [SUMMARY, VARCHAR, 40], [COMMENTS, VARCHAR, 400]]    Briefly a want to use this method for all database tables for updating